# If statement is not checking each value is selected

Tags: php

This if statement is not working. I am trying to make it so that all the things must contain a value for the first statement to be shown, but it works when only one value is selected.

```
   <?php

   if ((isset($_POST["FirstName"]))&&(isset($_POST['SecondName']))
        &&(isset($_POST['email']))&&(isset($_POST["submit"]))) {

   echo "You've given all your details";
   }        
   else {
   echo "Please enter all your details";
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: What is `not working` about it? getting an error message?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `var_export($_POST)` looks like when it fails?

Comment: What does `$_POST` look like when you var_dump it?

Comment: It's probably because they're set, but as an empty string.

Comment: Are you aware `isset()` can take several arguments ? Which means you could write a far shorter condition?

Comment: @greg0ire wow. I did **not** know that one. good tip ^_^

Comment: @greg0ire I rolled back. Don't change the OP. That is not what was asked. It was a good tip, but that does not mean to apply it to the OP.

Comment: I hesitated, but I think it is strictly equivalent, so, for readability's sake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i do when checking my form

```
    <?php

$firstname= $_POST['FirstName'];
$secondname = $_POST['SecondName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];


    if ($submit)
    {   
        if ($firstname&&$secondname&&$email)
        {

            echo "You've given all your details";

        }
    else
       echo "Please enter all your details";

    }
    ?>
```

but i may have miss understood what you are tying to do :), please do ignore this if this makes no sense at all (im still rather new to php)

Comment: :), i'm still new to it all lol, i just thought i would give it ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if the input is not filled it will be set. you need to check if it is set and if it contains input.

Try making a function to do just that:

```
function issetWithInput(&$va){
     return (isset($va) && !empty($va)); 
            //checks that it is set and contains input.
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
if(issetWithInput($_POST["FirstName"])&&issetWithInput($_POST['SecondName'])..) {
```

Comment: @RicardoCollins happy to help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['FirstName']) && 
    isset($_POST['SecondName']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['submit']) &&
    !empty($_POST['SecondName']) &&
    !empty($_POST['FirstName']) &&
    !empty($_POST['email'])) {

echo "You've given all your details";
}        
else {
echo "Please enter all your details";
}

?>
```

Comment: This will hit errors (or warnings) if anything is actually **not set**

Comment: Thanks for note that Neal, I've fix the code. Ricardo, please note that is better to ask for the variables to be set and then, ask to not been empty.